# How do I get every choice belonging to each poll?

Tags: python, html, django

Please I need help getting all queries. Here am getting just the data for the second poll only. I have two poll created but the data of the first one is not being sent to the front end if I use it to print it will be printed in the terminal. And I want to be able to allow a voter to vote on another poll even after they have voted, that is why I included the position in the voter model as ManyToMany Field

```
-------------------------------Models-----------------------------
class Voter(models.Model):
    gender_type = (('male', 'Male'), ('female', 'Female'))
    admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=gender_type)
    country_region = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=Countries.choices, default=Countries.Pakistan)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(blank=True, unique=True)
    otp = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    voted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    otp_sent = models.IntegerField(default=0)  # Control how many OTPs are sent
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(unique=True, default='ABC')
    position = models.ManyToManyField('Position', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.admin.first_name

    def get_voted_position(self):
        pass
    


class Position(models.Model):
    ACTIVE = 0
    INACTIVE = 1

    status_choice = ((ACTIVE, 'Active'), (INACTIVE, 'Inactive'))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    max_vote = models.IntegerField()
    priority = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(default=0, choices=status_choice)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def participants(self):
        participants = 0
        candidates = self.candidates.all()
        for candidate in candidates:
            participants += candidate.votes
        
        return participants


class Candidate(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="candidates")
    bio = models.TextField()
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='candidates')
    # votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fullname

    def calculate_votes(self):
        votes = self.votes.all()
        total_votes = 0
        for vote in votes:
            total_votes += vote.counter
        
        return total_votes
        



class Votes(models.Model):
    voter = models.ForeignKey(Voter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='positions')
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='votes')
    counter = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class BlockIP(models.Model):
    voter = models.ForeignKey(Voter, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ip')
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='positions_ip', null=True, blank=True)
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(default='abc')


@receiver(post_save, sender=Voter)
def default_to_non_active(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance = BlockIP.objects.create(voter=instance, ip_address=instance.ip_address)
        instance.save()

----------------------------#END OF MODELS
```

```
def index(request):
    context = {}
    instruction = ""
    candidate_data = []
    positions = Position.objects.order_by('priority').all()
   
    for position in positions:
        query = position.candidates.all()
        if position.max_vote > 1:
            instruction = "You may select up to " + str(position.max_vote) + " candidates"
        else:
            instruction = "Select a candidate"


    context = {
        'positions': positions,
        'query': query,
        'candidate_data': candidate_data,
        'instruction': instruction,
    }
    return render(request, 'poll/index.html', context)
```

This my frontend logic

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="mt-5">
    {% for position in positions %}
    {{ position.name }} <br>
    {{ instruction }} <br>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for c in query %}
        {{ c.fullname }}
        {{ c.id }}
        <p>{{ c.bio }}</p>
        <img src="/media/{{ c.photo }}" alt="" width="200" height="200">
      {% endfor %}
       
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I assume "instruction" and "query" should be variables bound to their corresponding position. Your code just handles them as single variables, both set in each position loop (and therefore overwritten in the second loop). 
You could use container dicts instead, containing the position model instance, the query and the instruction and pass them in an "positions" array to your render context.

Comment: Please can you show me an example

Answer (score 0):

> I assume "instruction" and "query" should be variables bound to their corresponding position. Your code just handles them as single variables, both set in each position loop (and therefore overwritten in the second loop). You could use container dicts instead, containing the position model instance, the query and the instruction and pass them in an "positions" array to your render context.

In your view:

```
positionList = []
for position in positions:
    rec = {}
    rec["position"] = position
    rec["query"] = position.candidates.all()
    if position.max_vote > 1:
        rec["instruction"] = "You may select up to " + str(position.max_vote) + " candidates"
    else:
        rec["instruction"] = "Select a candidate"
    positionList.append(rec)
    
...

context["positions"] = positionList
```

And in the template:

```
{% for position in positions %}
  {{ position.position.name }} <br />
  {{ position.instruction }}<br />
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please how do I then get all votes count for every candidate

Comment: I don't know how the data structure, I don't know about any votes... So I can't answer that.

Comment: I have included the data structure of my code, and what i want to archive